# Blender Hair with Dynamics explodes if i add collision

Tags: particles, hair, collision, dynamic

I want to add Hair Dynamics to fur so it reacts to wind and moves with the body's moving. When I add collision so the hair doesn’t go through the body the hair kinda explodes or goes away or jiggles and doesn’t react to the wind and moving dynamic… anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Update: I tried it on another scene just with a sphere. I make it small like "real size" (50 cm) which I need and applied the scale then the issues come up. If I scale it up and make it a little bigger as the default then everything works fine. Do you know how I can fix this? So which settings are needed to get a proper simulation at a smaller size?

Comment: Questions that are short, do not contain a visual like a screen-capture (showing settings or results) and the like may not get a helpful response.

Comment: Not knowing your settings on the hair, may I suggest that you look at Hair Dynamics at *Impulse clamping* and *Stiffness* and the collision is against a character with a complex mesh, there are often wild dynamics with hair or cloth.

Comment: @james_t so i tried it on another scene just With a sphere… i make it small like „real size“ 50cm what i Need and Applied the scale then the issues come up… if i scale it up and make it a Little bigger as the default then everything works fine … do u Know how i can fix this? So which settings are needed to get a proper Simulation at a smaller size

Comment: Good clue.  I've reproduced your problem now and can spend a few moments fiddling.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem !!! When there is no collider everything works fine, the moment I declare a collider everything goes wild...